# Not able to produce to 3.2.1 secure kafka(SASL_PLAINTEXT and SCRAM-SHA-512) using the nifi 1.9.2

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-nifi

I need to consume from 0.8.2.1 version kafka using the GetKafka in nifi which we are using the version 1.9.2. From there using the PublishKafka_2_0 in same 1.9.2 nifi I need to send to the same topic for the kafka 3.2.1 cluster which is having the SASL_PLAINTEXT security and SCRAM-SHA-512. when i configured all the required things like username and password and sasl.jaas.config dynamically it is asking for the kerberos service name . After few debugging and study I found that SASL_PLAINTEXT is only supported with GSAPI which is Kerberos.

But then i tried with upgraded nifi version 1.18.0 which i can use the PublishKafka_2_6 where i can quite comfortably produce to the secured topic on 3.2.1 version kafka which is of SASL_PLAINTEXT and SCRAM-SHA-512 . But here issue is in this version of nifi(1.18.0) there is no GetKafka inorder to consumer from the 0.8.2.1 kafka topic.

how to resolve this issue as i cannot find any solution to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to obtain any of the older NARs that are no longer included by default by going to Maven central:

https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/nifi/nifi-kafka-0-8-nar/

Comment: hello @bryan thanks for replying . ok I just want to get some clarification downloading the nar file and providing it in the nar files of the nifi 1.18.0 is the solution you are saying.

It would be a really helpful if you provide me the steps for it to resolve this.

Comment: The help would be highly appreciable. hoping you would reply again.

Comment: I mean time i would go through some blogs how to do this .

thanks for the reply

Comment: Thanks @Bryan for your help I was able to work on this and now as you said commited the 1.9.2 nar file in the lib path of the 1.18.0 nifi and restarted and then I was able to see GetKafka now and able to consume from 0.8.2.1 kafka and able to produce to the 3.2.1 kafka with the security which is SASL_PLAINTEXT and SCRAM-SHA-256. Thank you

Comment: this can also be done with following in 1.9.2 nifi only by following steps . you can consume from 0.8.2.1 kafka using GetKafka and for producing to the 3.2.1 kafka on security of SASL_PLAINTEXT and SCRAM-SHA-512 as below

keep Security.Protocol as SASL_PLAINTEXT
add the dynamic properties as below---
 
sasl.jaas.config --  org.apache.kafka.common.security.scram.ScramLoginModule required username="username" password="password";
sasl.mechanism -- SCRAM-SHA-512
Kerberos Service Name   --- kafka
Use Transactions   --- false 

this will work